# Lotus Notes 7 - Categorized column issue

Tags: view, lotus-notes

There are 2 forms "fmA" and "fmB". In "fmA" I have to possibility to create "fmB", by taking a field value and the UNID from "fmA" into 2 fields in "fmB". eg: Company Name and txt_UNID ( which is computed ) in "fmA" goes into "fmB" in Company Name and txt_UNIDB.

There is a possibility to create "fmB" without being a connexion with "fmA": create "fmB" from a view action, outside the form of "fmA".

In my main view, I want to display all these documents ( fmA & fmB ) and I create a first column which is categorized and hidden, having the following formula:

@If(Form="fmA";txt_UNID;txt_UNIDB)

It displays OK, but is there any possibility to not show the 'invisible' twisty ( which in this case is invisible but I can collapse / expand any category of docs. ) ?

I got smth like this:

(invisible line in view, but still I can collapse/expand the categories )

1st doc from fmA

```
  1st doc from fmB  
  2nd doc from fmB
```

(invisible line in view, but still I can collapse/expand the categories )

2nd doc from fmA

```
  1st doc from fmB
```

(invisible line in view, but still I can collapse/expand the categories )

```
  1st doc from fmB ( which doesn't depends on any fmA)
  2nd doc from fmB ( which doesn't depends on any fmA)
  3rd doc from fmB ( which doesn't depends on any fmA)
```

Thanks for your time and help! I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want categories... don't categorize the view. In your case it is enough to SORT with this hidden column, you don't need to categorize it.

Nevertheless there is an option called "Categorized is flat version 5 or greater" in the column properties that hides the categories, but I don't see the advantage of having such a column instead of a simple sorted one...

Comment: Thank you Tode! That was what I was looking for! THanks for your help and tips!

Comment: I will create another question, even if it refers at same tags: view. Thanks again!