# Lotus Notes 7 - Categorized column and display docs in view

Tags: view, lotus-notes

Today I've received an answer which helped me at this topic : [Lotus Notes 7 - Categorized column issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17828293/lotus-notes-7-categorized-column-issue) .

For this topic, the scenario is quite similarly: there are 2 forms: "fmA" and "fmB", "fmB" may be connected with "fmA" by its UNID or may be not.

The "fmB" has a field - checkbox with Yes or NO as options. This field doesn't exist on "fmA". What I want to display is smth like this:

1st doc from fmA

```
  YES

      1st doc from fmB ( that depends on 1st doc from fmA) with checkbox = YES

      2nd doc from fmB -----------||--------------------   with checkbox = YES  

  NO
      1st doc from fmB ( that depends on 1st doc from fmA) with checkbox = NO

      2nd doc from fmB -----------||--------------------   with checkbox = NO
```

YES

1st doc from fmB ( which doesn't depends on any fmA) with checkbox = YES

2nd doc from fmB ( which doesn't depends on any fmA) with checkbox = YES

NO

1st doc from fmB ( which doesn't depends on any fmA) with checkbox = NO

My first column is hided and ascending having a formula :

@If(Form="fmA";txt_UNID;txt_UNIDB)

and the second one have the following formula:

@If(Form="fmA";@Return("");checkbox="Yes";"YES";checkbox="No";"NO";"")

But the docs are displayed strangely and not together ( where it is the case ).

I appreciate any help! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just switch the two columns...

View Selection formula: `SELECT Form = "fmB"` (no need to show fmA- docs)

First Column, Categorized: `@If( checkbox="Yes";"YES";checkbox="No";"NO";"")` or easier: `@Uppercase( checkbox )`

Second column, categorized flat (or sorted only): `txt_UNIDB`

Comment: Thanks again Tode. But in the view i want to display also the "fmA" docs, so why no need to show fmA- docs?

Comment: Because, I want at those docs. which depends on fmA, at top of the YES or NO categories to appear the fmA that contains them.

Comment: No chance to do this without updating docs of fmA on each save of fmB like this: Checkbox in fmA is Multi- Value. If there is ONE fmB pointing to fmA with "YES", then add value "YES" to checkbox in fmA. if there is at least ONE fmB pointing to fmA with "NO" then add value "NO" to fmA... in fmA there are 4 possible combinations of values : "" (no fmB for fmA, probably exlude them from view), "YES": Only documents of fmB with "YES", "NO": Only documents of fmB with "NO", "YES" : "NO": fmB with YES and NO exist... There is NO other possibility to do this.

Comment: I understand... So, there should be a checkbox also on fmA ?